# Android google directions api json response handling language text

Tags: android, maps, driving-directions

I am calling google directions api for getting direction json and pasring it.

```
String html_instructions =((JSONObject) jSteps.get(k)).getString("html_instructions");
html_instructions = Html.fromHtml(html_instructions).toString();
```

it is handling unicode but not handling language text.

**Response**

```
"html_instructions" : "Turn \u003cb\u003eleft\u003c/b\u003e onto \u003cb\u003eNH 75\u003c/b\u003e\u003cdiv style=\"font-size:0.9em\"\u003eContinue to follow ஆசிய நெடுஞ்சாலை 43\u003c/div\u003e\u003cdiv style=\"font-size:0.9em\"\u003ePartial toll road\u003c/div\u003e\u003cdiv style=\"font-size:0.9em\"\u003ePass by Deep Automobiles (on the right in 222&nbsp;km)\u003c/div\u003e"
```

**Result how it is showing**
[image]